# Getting a count from multiple columns with set values in SQL and MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of information with multiple columns but each column can hold only 1 of 3 values (0,1,2). It is generated through user inputted choices of Yes, No Maybe. I want to count each column and be fed back the values.

EG Table:

```
ID  Coffee  Tea   Water   Hot_Choc
1      1     0      2        2
2      0     2      0        1
3      1     2      0        2
4      2     0      1        1
5      1     1      2        2
6      0     1      2        1
7      2     1      0        1
8      1     2      1        2
```

I'd like to query the data to an output like this:

```
    Coffee  Tea   Water   Hot_Choc
0      2     2      3        0
1      4     3      2        4
2      2     3      3        4
```

I tried running a basic count script:
SELECT coffee, count(*) FROM Drinks GROUP BY coffee

Which works fine.

and then tried evolving into:
SELECT coffee,tea,water,hot_choc, count(*) from Drinks group by coffee,tea,water,hot_choc

But with that I get a count for each instance. So when coffee is 0 what are the counts for tea, water and hot_choc.

I also tried with a sum(iif clause because I'm running in access:

```
select sum(iif(coffee=0,1,0)) as coffee_maybe,
sum(iif(coffee=1,1,0)) as coffee_no,
sum(iif(coffee=2,1,0)) as coffee_yes from drinks;
etc.
```

Which gets me this:

```
Coffee_maybe coffee_no coffee_yes tea_maybe tea_no tea_yes etc...
     2            4        2         2        3       2
```

So I'm wondering if anyone has other thoughts as to how to get the count in the above format.

Thanks so much for the help, sorry it's been a long read I wanted to give as much context as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following will work in Access:

```
select 0, sum(iif(coffee = 0, 1, 0)) as coffee, sum(iif(tea = 0, 1, 0)) as tea,
       sum(iif(water = 0, 1, 0)) as water, sum(iif(hot_choc = 0, 1, 0)) as hot_choc
from drinks d
union all
select 1, sum(iif(coffee = 1, 1, 0)) as coffee, sum(iif(tea = 1, 1, 0)) as tea,
       sum(iif(water = 1, 1, 0)) as water, sum(iif(hot_choc = 1, 1, 0)) as hot_choc
from drinks d
union all
select 2, sum(iif(coffee = 2, 1, 0)) as coffee, sum(iif(tea = 2, 1, 0)) as tea,
       sum(iif(water = 2, 1, 0)) as water, sum(iif(hot_choc = 2, 1, 0)) as hot_choc
from drinks d;
```

There are slightly easier ways to do this in other databases.

Comment: Worked fine, the only thing I needed to change was Access wasn't letting me use the same column names so I had to name them coffee1 tea1 etc but the union still worked great. Thanks again